# I am new to R language, I want to get excel equivalent formula?

Tags: r, excel, excel-formula

Please if now you can help! I have applied these four formula in excel to get the results;
`if_has_Parent` column in excel has formula: `IF(E2="",0,2)` in R I tried using `ifelse` and it worked;
`if_has_children` column in excel has formula: `IF(F2="",0,COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,F2))` I'm unable to do in R;
`if_has_siblings` column in excel has formula: `(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,E2))-1`;
Summing the results of these give me the result of my query i.e total no of first degree relatives:=`P2+Q2+S2`

Please help me to do in R.

```
structure(list(pedid = c(0L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L,
10L, 10L), indid = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L),
Gender = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Age = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Child_of_family = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Family = c(NA, NA, NA, 
1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA), UIndID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Mortality = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Suicide = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Xcoord = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 480L, 560L, 315L, 385L, 
450L, 525L, 545L), Ycoord = c(0L, 0L, 0L, -25L, -25L, -105L, 
-105L, -105L, -145L, -100L), First_Name = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Disease_in_Individual_code = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Onset_disease_age = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 999L, 999L, 999L, 999L), Disease_in_Individual_name = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "Alzheimer's Dementia", "Alzheimer's Dementia", 
"Alzheimer's Dementia", "Alzheimer's Dementia"), If.has.Parent. = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), If.has.Children. = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), If.has.siblings. = c(-1L, 
 -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), If.has.siblings..1 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Total.Number.of.First.Degree.Relatives = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Hey, richa. What is you desirable result?

Comment: I have to find total number of first degree relatives. So first i have used formula in excel to find if given individuals have parents, children and siblings. After summing the results of three i get answer to desired query i.e total number of first degree relatives. The pedid means pedigree ID, indid means individual id,child_of_family column is showing to which family child belongs and family column is showing which two individuals make a family. The individual Id is unique(1-20) for one pedid 10 and than again individual ID is (1-25) for Pedid 11 in same excel sheet.

Comment: the individual id may repeat twice for same pedid if person has two diseases.

Comment: If you want to solve this in R, don't use excel terms because folks might not be aware of it. Please update your post with the expected output that you want to achieve.

Comment: i have already explained the problem and what i want to achieve in my comments. Please read. If i knew how to apply logic in R i have not posted my question. I want to achieve total number of first degree relatives from the data provided to me.

Comment: i want the equivalent logic for (COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,E2)) function of excel in R. I think it is not very complicated function of excel.

Comment: if you can reconstruct the above data you can see how achieved solution in excel. But problem is i have large data solving it in excel is making it so time consuming process.